# Server returns "not logged-in" when using fetch api

Tags: react-native, fetch

I'm sending request to instagram.com/p/SHORTCODE url on Postman and it give me a proper response. But when i try that request using fetch api on react-native, it doesn't give the same response. It gives an html doc starting with:

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in ">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">       

    <title>
              Page Not Found &bull; Instagram
            </title>
```

Is it related to the browser that i use with Postman ? I'm copying all the cookies from Postman reqest to fetch api. It should give me the same response but it does not.

Comment: You should try copying Postman's headers into fetch. Postman adds some standard headers to simplify developer's life.

Comment: @AlexanderSantos I did, i'm copying the exact fetch code from postman with the headers